# jquery how to use find() to find the variable inside the script tag?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, find

I have the webpage with a `<script> var nUos={//json} </script>` how can i get that variable using find? Not sure if i can use that.

//
if you are a Wordpress user I have a variable that is dynamic being passed to the WordPress pages using localize script functionality
Please help

Comment: Can you describe the actual problem that you're trying to solve?  eg is it that you don't know the name of the variable (`nUos`)?

Comment: @freedomn-m yeah that is the actual problem. I won't know the variable in the javascript file. Though the variable is in the HTML generated

Comment: This seems to be an X/Y question as you're asking about your attempted solution, rather than describing the problem. While it's certainly possible to find a `<script>` tag based on the content within it, it serves absolutely no purpose. You cannot amend the content of the tag, nor would removing or amending the tag do anything as the content has already been loaded and executed. So, what is the actual issue you want to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using `wp_localize_script` (something) like:

```
wp_localize_script('my-script', 'nUos', array('foo' => 'bar'));
```

`nUos` will be made available to you by means of the `window` object:

```
console.log(window.nUos)

//-> {foo: "bar"}
```

Sidenote: `nUos` is not JSON, it is a JS object literal.